# Graphql create relations between two queries.Error cannot access before initialization

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, graphql, express-graphql

I have this code:

```
const ProductType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Product',
    fields: {
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        category: {
            type: CategoryType,
            resolve: async (parent) => {
                return await Category.findOne({_id: parent.category});
            }
        }
    }
});

const CategoryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Category',
    fields: {
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        products: {
            type: ProductType,
            resolve: async (parent, args) => {
                return await Product.find({category: parent._id});
            }
        }
    }
});

const Query = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
        Categories: {
            type: new GraphQLList(CategoryType),
            resolve: async () => {
                return await Category.find();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

When i try to compile i get ReferenceError: Cannot access 'CategoryType' before initialization.
I understand that first of all I should declare and only after that use, but I saw a similar code in one lesson on YouTube, and I think that it should work, but it’s not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fields` can take a function instead of an object. This way the code inside the function won't be evaluated immediately:

```
fields: () => ({
  id: { type: GraphQLID },
  name: { type: GraphQLString },
  category: {
    type: CategoryType,
    resolve: (parent) => Category.findOne({_id: parent.category}),
  }
})
```

Comment: Could you please let me know, which is faster the above code or using buildSchema or graphql-tools ?

Comment: @Muhammad Your schema will only be built once when you first start your server. Any differences in speed between these different approaches are negligible and will not impact the rate at which your server is able to process requests.

Comment: thank you very much, please let me know, would you suggest us to use `graphql-tools` for schema language ? or it is better we use like javascript functions `fields(), resovle` as here exist in this code ??? and is `graphql-tools` developed by Facebook ?