# My ObjectType is returning an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql, graphql-js

So i have two objecttypes and i'm trying to include them to make relationships, one of them works and one of them just returns an empty object and i can't figure out why.

this one works, it console logs the ranktype and works fine

```js
const Rank = require('../model/RankModel')
const { RankType } = require('./rank')
console.log(RankType)

/**
 * Defines Branch Type
 */
const BranchType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Branch",
  fields: {
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    color: { type: GraphQLString },
    ranks: { 
      type: GraphQLList(RankType),
      resolve: async (branch) => {
        return await Rank.find({branch: branch.id})
      }
    }
  }
})
module.exports.BranchType = BranchType
```

this is the one thats breaking

```js
const Rank = require('../model/RankModel')
const Branch = require('../model/BranchModel')
const { BranchType } = require('./branch')

console.log(BranchType)
/**
 * Defines Rank Type
 */
const RankType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Rank",
  fields: {
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    shortHand: { type: GraphQLString },
    branch: { 
      type: BranchType,
      resolve: async (rank) => {
        return await Branch.findById(rank.branch)
      }
    }
  }
})
module.exports.RankType = RankType
```

this givs me an error of "message": "The type of Rank.branch must be Output Type but got: undefined."

**Models/Relations:**

BranchModel:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let branchSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  color: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  ranks: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Rank'
  }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Branch', branchSchema)
```

RankModel

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

let rankSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  shortHand: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  branch: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Branch'
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Rank', rankSchema);
```

**Answer!!!!!!**

```js
/**
 * Defines Rank Type
 */
const RankType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Rank",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    shortHand: { type: GraphQLString },
    branch: { 
      type: require('./branch').BranchType,
      resolve: async (rank) => {
        console.log(rank.branch)
        return await Branch.findById(rank.branch)
      }
    }
  })
})
module.exports.RankType = RankType
```

Comment: are you trying to resolve `branch` field using `rank.branch`, field being resolved?

Comment: @xadm yes as the objectID is linked to rank.branch. However when I console.log BranchType it is returning undefined in this rank.js file. When i require it and console.log it in my user.js file it works fine

Comment: how value can be defined by reading the same value (not defined earlier)?

Comment: @xadm The issue I'm having is {BranchType} is undefined. Else everything would work. For some reason even though I'm exporting the const BranchType its undefined in this specific file. When i require it in another file it works fine. I just don't know why it would be undefined in this file. It works if i comment out Rank.branch but {BranchType} is still undefined either way

Comment: IMHO you're trying to use `rank.branch` value while it is undefined ... try `resolve: async (rank) => { console.log(rank.branch);
        return await Branch.findById(rank.branch)` - undefined argument, no object found/returned

Comment: You have a circular dependency between your modules. Rank requires Branch which requires Rank which requires Branch and so on. See the linked post for suggestions on how to deal with this scenario in general. In GraphQL.js specifically, you can sometimes negate it by using a thunk instead of an object for `fields`.

Comment: @DanielRearden I'm unsure what you mean by using a thunk. I just started using graphql yesterday. I've searched online but can't find anything of help

Comment: show models/relation

Comment: @xadm I've updated the post with my models

Comment: Instead of an object, `fields` can take a function that returns an object. `fields: () => ({ branch, ... })` This delays the evaluation of the code inside the function until it is called. So you could, for example, call require inside there to delay its evaluation, thereby avoiding the cyclic requires.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60139576/6124657 - but this is not exactly about dependency - resolving flow?

Comment: @DanielRearden Your a god among men. You have fixed my issues!! Thank you

Comment: @Riley post an answer/solution

Comment: @xadm posted one

Answer (score -1):

Looks to me like you need to destructure BranchType like you did when requiring RankType, based what I can see from your module.exports

change

```
const BranchType = require('./branch')
```

to

```
const { BranchType } = require('./branch')
```

Comment: I've tried that, it should have been in the code iwas just editing some things. When i do that i get this error: "message": "The type of Rank.branch must be Output Type but got: undefined."